# Get value from textboxes inside dynamic table using selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alert, html5

I am creating one row every time im clicking on the btn Add row. In this row there is 3 textboxes and one lable(span) and one buttom. I want to reach by selector the value in the (input type:text) or the lable using the button in the created row (save projekt) to save this value in my Sharepoint hosted list. How can I do that please.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="content">
<table id="Table">
</table>              
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="add()">Add row</button>
```

This is my jquery code

```
function add() {

$("#Table").append("<tr class=\"tr\">" +
"<td><input type=\"text\"></td>" +
"<td><input type=\"text\"></td>" +
"<td><input type=\"text\"></td>" +
"<td><span \" class=\"lblStatus\"></span></td>" +
"<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"saveProjekt\">Save projekt</button></td>" +
"</tr>").trigger("create");
}

 $(document).on("click", ".saveProjekt", function (e) {
 var x1 = $(e.target).parent().parent().children("td .input:nth child(1)").val();
 var x2 = $(e.target).parent().parent().children("td .input:nth child(2)").val();
 alert(x1);
 alert(x2);
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create HTML as below

```
<div class="content">
<table id="Table">
    <tr class="tr">
        <td><input type="text" class="Text1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="Text2"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="Text3"/></td>
    <td><span class="lblStatus"></span></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="saveProjekt" tag="0">Save projekt</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>              
</div>
```

Now you can use below JavaScript for reading values

```
$(document).on("click", ".saveProjekt", function (e) {
    var text1, text2, text3, status;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("class") == "Text1") text1 = $(this).val();
        if($(this).attr("class") == "Text2") text1 = $(this).val();
        if($(this).attr("class") == "Text2") text1 = $(this).val();
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').find('span').each(function(){
        status = $(this).text();
    }
 });
```